# Update users email address through powershell for AzureAD

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I was wondering if someone could help, we have some users in our organisation who are using uppercase email address, certain applications can't recognize this and fail. I have developed the script below to change the users UPN and display names to lowercase, however this doesn't change their email address. I don't want to create new mailboxes as there are several hundred users that have the incorrect format. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be a great help.

```
#Install-module AzureAD
#Connect-AzureAD
$Users = Get-azureADUser -filter "userPrincipalName eq 'User1@MyDomain.com'" 
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$OutputObj  = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
$OutputObj1 = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
$SuccessOutput = @() 
$ErrorOutput = @() 
$Case = "toLower"
Function ChangeToLowerCase{

Try{
foreach ($user in $users) {
 $user | Set-AzureADUser -userPrincipalName $user.userPrincipalName.$Case()
 $user | Set-AzureADUser -identity $user.SipProxyAddress.$Case()


 #$User | Select-Object DisplayName, userPrincipalName,Mail
 $OutputObj  | Add-Member -memberType NoteProperty -name "Display Name" -value $($user.DisplayName)
 $OutputObj  | Add-Member -memberType NoteProperty -name "UPN" -value $($user.userPrincipalName)
 $OutputObj  | Add-Member -memberType NoteProperty -name "Email Address" -value $($user.Mail)
 $SuccessOutput +=$OutputObj
 $SuccessOutput | Export-csv "C:\Temp\Powershell\Completed\UPN Changes.csv" -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber -Append
  }
}
Catch{
$OutputObj1 | Add-Member -memberType NoteProperty -name "Display Name" -value $($user.DisplayName)
$OutputObj1 | Add-Member -memberType NoteProperty -name "Error Message" -value $($_.Exception.Message)
$ErrorOutput +=$OutputObj1
$ErrorOutput | Export-csv "C:\Temp\Powershell\Errors\UPN Changes Error.csv" -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber -Append
}
}
ChangeToLowerCase
```

I am looking at the Set-AzureAduser property, however I am unable to change the mail property in this variable.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-convert-all-uppercase-string-to-lowercase/

Comment: @Matthew - this is great, but it doesn't allow you to update the mail field, just keeps erroring, saying that it think I am after mailnickname. I have tried several options on how to get this to update, but none have worked, if anyone could advise on how to get this to work, surely it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Nice, I had the same issue after we added a domain with a capital W. It wont change the email address because it's not case sensitive.

I created this to resolve the issue:

```
function ConvertTo-LowerW
{

  foreach ($Recipient in $Recipients)
  { 
  "1"
  $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress

  $SplitEmail = $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress.Split('@')
  $BeforeA = $SplitEmail | Select-Object -First 1
  $AfterA = ($SplitEmail | Select-Object -Last 1).ToLower()
  $NewPrimarySmtpAddress = $BeforeA + '@' + $AfterA

  $NewPrimarySmtpAddress

  switch ($Recipient.RecipientType)
  {

     'UserMailbox'
     {
        try
        {
           $Addresses = (Get-Mailbox -Identity $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress  -ErrorAction Stop).EmailAddresses
           $Addresses = $Addresses.Replace("SMTP:$($recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress)", "")

           Set-Mailbox -ErrorAction Stop `
              -Identity $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress `
              -EmailAddresses $NewPrimarySmtpAddress 

           if ($Addresses.Length -ne 0)
           {
              foreach ($Address in ($Addresses | Where-Object { $_.Length -ne 0 }) )
              {
                 $Address
                 if ($Address.Length -ne 0 )
                 {
                    Set-Mailbox -ErrorAction Stop `
                       -Identity $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress `
                       -EmailAddresses @{add = "$Address" } 
                 }
              }
           }
        }

        Catch
        {
           $ErrorList.Add($Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress)
           $ErrorList.Add($_.Exception.Message)      

        }

     }

     'MailUniversalDistributionGroup'
     {
        try
        {
           $Addresses = (Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress -ErrorAction Stop).EmailAddresses
           $Addresses = $Addresses.Replace("SMTP:$($recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress)", "")

           Set-DistributionGroup -ErrorAction Stop `
              -Identity $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress `
              -EmailAddresses $NewPrimarySmtpAddress 

           if ($Addresses.Length -ne 0)
           {
              foreach ($Address in  ($Addresses | Where-Object { $Addresses.Length -ne 0 }))
              {
                 if ($Address.Length -ne 0 )
                 {
                    Set-DistributionGroup -ErrorAction Stop `
                       -Identity $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress `
                       -EmailAddresses @{add = "$Address" } 
                 }
              }
           }
        }
        catch
        {
           $ErrorList.Add($Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress)
           $ErrorList.Add($_.Exception.Message)      
        }

     }

     'DynamicDistributionGroup'
     {
        try
        {
           $Addresses = (Get-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress -ErrorAction Stop).EmailAddresses
           $Addresses = $Addresses.Replace("SMTP:$($recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress)", "")

           Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -ErrorAction Stop `
              -Identity $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress `
              -EmailAddresses $NewPrimarySmtpAddress 

           if ($Addresses.Length -ne 0)
           {
              foreach ($Address in  ($Addresses | Where-Object { $Addresses.Length -ne 0 }))
              {
                 $Address
                 if ($Address.Length -ne 0 )
                 {
                    Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -ErrorAction Stop `
                       -Identity $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress `
                       -EmailAddresses @{add = "$Address" } 
                 }
              }
           }
        }
        catch
        {
           $ErrorList.Add($Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress)
           $ErrorList.Add($_.Exception.Message)      
        }
     }

     Default
     {
        try
        {

           $Recipient.RecipientType
           $Recipient.RecipientTypeDetails
           'User has an unrecognized Recipienttype'

           Send-Email `
              -To $to `
              -Body 'Test' `
              -Subject 'User has an unrecognized Recipienttype' 
        }
        catch
        {
           $ErrorList += "$($($Recipient).PrimarySmtpAddress) has an unrecognized RecipientType $($($Recipient).Recipienttype)"
           $ErrorList.Add($Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress)
           $ErrorList.Add($_.Exception.Message)      
        }
     }
  }
   }
 }
```

I'll see if I can create a blog post on [bwit.blog](https://bwit.blog) regarding this.

Comment: Thanks for this, can I ask what is in the variable $Recipient - I am trying to now use this script as a subscript to the above, so that I can get the primarySMTPAddress to continue your script. I have so far "$Global:SM = Get-Mailbox -Identity $Account '| FL'" - but this doesn't allow your script to find $_.PrimarySMTPAddress. Thanks for the help